# Query AWS CLI to populate Jenkins "Active Choices Reactive Parameter" (Linux)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, aws-cli

I have a Jenkins 2.0 job where I require the user to select the list of servers to execute the job against via a Jenkins "Active Choices Reactive Parameter".  These servers which the job will execute against are AWS EC2 instances.  Instead of hard-coding the available servers in the "Active Choices Reactive Parameter", I'd like to query the AWS CLI to get a list of servers.

A few notes:

- I've assigned the Jenkins 2.0 EC2 an IAM role which has sufficient privileges to query AWS via the CLI.
- The AWS CLI is installed on the Jenkins EC2.
- The "Active Choices Reactive Parameter" will return a list of checkboxes if I hardcode values in a Groovy script, such as:
  return ["10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2", 10.1.1.3"]
- I know my awk commands can be improved, I'm not yet sure how, but my primary goal is to get the list of servers dynamically loaded in Jenkins.

I can run the following command directly on the EC2 instance which is hosting Jenkins:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-2 --filters
   "Name=tag:Env,Values=qa" --query
   "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" | grep -o
   '\"[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\"' | awk
   {'printf $0 ", "'} | awk {'print "[" $0'} | awk {'gsub(/^[ \t]+|[
   \t]+$/, ""); print'} | awk {'print substr ($0, 1, length($0)-1)'} |
   awk {'print $0 "]"'}
```

This will return the following, which is in the format expected by the "Active Choices Reactive Parameter":

```
["10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2", 10.1.1.3"]
```

So, in the "Script" textarea of the "Active Choices Reactive Parameter", I have the following script.  The problem is that my server list is never populated.  I've tried numerous variations of this script without luck.  Can someone please tell me where I've went wrong and what I can do to correct this script so that my list of server IP addresses is dynamically loaded into a Jenkins job?

```
def standardOut = new StringBuffer(), standardErr = new StringBuffer()

def command = $/
    aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-2 --filters "Name=tag:Env,Values=qaint" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" | 
    grep -o '\"[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\"' | 
    awk {'printf $0 ", "'} | 
    awk {'print "[" $0'} | 
    awk {'gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print'} | 
    awk {'print substr ($0, 1, length($0)-1)'} | 
    awk {'print $0 "]"'}
    /$

def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(standardOut, standardErr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)

return standardOut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to execute your script and the standardErr had some errors, Looks like groovy didn't like the double quotes in the AWS CLI. Here is a cleaner way to do without using awk

```
def command = 'aws ec2 describe-instances \
               --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=Test \
               --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress \
               --output text'
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode= proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text

if (error) {
    println "Std Err: ${error}"
    println "Process exit code: ${exitcode}"
    return exitcode
}

//println output.split()
return output.split()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I was not able to get your code working as is, I don't know what the problem with it was.

How are you viewing standardErr?  Are you just manually executing the groovy script on the Jenkins server, or is there a way to view the standardErr from within the Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Parameter?  I'm struggling with debugging stuff like this in Jenkins, I haven't found a way to really do it.

Comment: Here's the code I was able to get working:

`def standardOut = new StringBuffer(), standardErr = new StringBuffer()
def command


 command = $/
    aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-2 
    --filters Name=tag:Env,Values=qa 
    --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress 
    --output text
   /$
 def proc = command.execute()

 proc.consumeProcessOutput(standardOut, standardErr)
 proc.waitForOrKill(10000)



return standardOut.tokenize()`

Comment: just print the standardErr, I tested with groovy, not with Jenkins, Please accept the answer if it helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This script works with Jenkins Active Choices Parameter, and returns the list of IP addresses:

```
def aws_cmd = 'aws ec2 describe-instances \
               --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
                         Name=tag:env,Values=dev \
               --query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress[] \
               --region us-east-2 \
               --output text'

def aws_cmd_output = aws_cmd.execute()
// probably is required if execution takes long
//aws_cmd_output.waitFor() 
def ip_list = aws_cmd_output.text.tokenize()

return ip_list
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tired all the above option and im not getting the value
could someone advice is this the correct format

[$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
description: 'Select the Environemnt from the Dropdown List',
filterLength: 1,
filterable: false,
name: 'GoldenImage',
script: [
$class: 'GroovyScript',
script: [
classpath: [],
sandbox: true,
script: '''
def aws_cmd = 'aws ec2 describe-instances 
--filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running 
Name=tag:env,Values=dev 
--query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress[] 
--region us-east-2 
--output text'

```
                                            def aws_cmd_output = aws_cmd.execute()
                                            // probably is required if execution takes long
                                            //aws_cmd_output.waitFor() 
                                            def ip_list = aws_cmd_output.text.tokenize()

                                            return ip_list
                                            '''
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).